# MYSQL Limit Occurences of a particular column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Pulling some coupons from a database. Each coupon has a `merchantid` column that contains the id for the merchant for which the coupon belongs too.

I'm trying to construct a query that pulls 5 coupons, but I only want 1 coupon per `merchantid`. I don't want multiple coupons with the same `merchantid`.

Comment: do you want a random selection or just some distinct rows?

Comment: In the query I'm trying to sort by numberofclicks first, and then take the coupons with the highest number of clicks per retailer. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```sql
SELECT * FROM coupons GROUP BY merchantid LIMIT 0,5;
```

And it **will** work because

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause ([see docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html))

If you don't want MySQL to decide which `merchantid` to keep, you can add your condition 
(in example below - keep merchant with highest number of clicks) using subquery:

**FIXED:**

```sql
SELECT c1.* 
FROM coupons c1 JOIN (
    SELECT t.merchantid, MAX(t.numberofclicks) maxnumberofclicks
    FROM coupons t GROUP BY t.merchantid
) c2 ON c1.merchantid = c2.merchantid AND c1.numberofclicks = c2.maxnumberofclicks 
LIMIT 0,5;
```

And one more (more concise and probably faster on large datasets) way to skin a cat:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM coupons c1 JOIN coupons c2 ON c1.merchantid = c2.merchantid
GROUP BY c1.merchantid, c1.numberofclicks
HAVING c1.numberofclicks = MAX(c2.numberofclicks)
LIMIT 0,5;
```

If you want 5 coupons with overall highest number of clicks, add `ORDER BY c1.numberofclicks DESC` before `LIMIT 0,5`.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this query. I have some WHERE conditions that need to go in there as well. This what I have so far,its pulling only 1 coupon per merchant, but the coupon its pulling doesn't have the highest clicks:

SELECT C.couponid,C.fmtc_couponid,C.merchantid,C.label,C.restrictions,C.coupon,C.link,C.image,C.expire,C.unknown,C.clicks,M.name,M.approved,M.homepageurl,M.logo_image,M.permalink FROM tblCoupons C,tblMerchants M WHERE C.merchantid=M.merchantid  AND C.begin <  ".mktime()." AND C.expire > ".mktime()." AND M.display='1' GROUP BY C.merchantid ORDER BY C.clicks DESC LIMIT 0,6

Comment: `GROUP BY` is performed prior to `ORDER BY`, so you're ordering already 'randomly' filtered records. Use my second or third example, just add `JOIN tblMerchants ON tblMerchants.merchantid = tblCouopns.merchantid` and  `ORDER BY clicks` before `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name GROUP BY merchantid LIMIT 0,5;
```

this would give 5 rows which has distinct merchantid's, but you may get the same result for different executions. if you want to randomize it, randomize `'A'` inside `'LIMIT A,5'`.

Comment: but i'm not sure how group by works! so you might get the same row among the ones which have same merchantid's AT ALL TIMES!

Comment: This should not work at all, as `*` is not part of the GROUP BY clause or part of a aggregate function.

Comment: This WORKS successfully. Thanks. However, in the query I'm trying to sort by numberofclicks first, and then take the coupons with the highest number of clicks per retailer. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: use the solution @lxa gives. :)