# Sorting by a to z with Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, top-n

I have one table **customers** which has one field '**name**' with a to z names records.

I get records from a to z with asc query

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY name ASC
```

**But how can i get 5 records which starts with all a to z alphabets with only one query?**

Output:

1. a
2. a
3. a
4. a
5. a
6. b
7. b
8. b
9. b
10. b
    and so on to z.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this need to be done as a single sql statement/query, or can a stored procedure/function be called to provide the results?

Comment: @Raad as a single query.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656316/mysql-limit-occurences-of-a-particular-column-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM (SELECT c.name, IF(@lastLetter=@lastLetter:=LEFT(c.name, 1), @cnt:=@cnt+1, @cnt:=0) letterCnt
      FROM customers c, (SELECT @lastLetter:='', @cnt:=0) A 
      ORDER BY c.name ASC
    ) AS c
WHERE c.letterCnt < 5
```

Comment: Saharsh Shah i am getting result in mysql but not in sqlite. Can u help me for sqlite?

Comment: @TonyStark Sorry, I'm newbie to sqllite.

Comment: I am getting this error [unrecognized token: ":"], if u can help me.

Comment: @TonyStark Sorry but I can't help you for SQLLite

Comment: Ok np. Thanks for the answer but i will accept it later. i need it in sqlite also(but i can give u upvote). can u little bit explain about ur query? its amazing.

Answer (score -1):

When you use SQL you can use functions like [Rank](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), [DENSE_RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) and ROW_NUMBER

```
DECLARE @Customer AS TABLE
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Customer VALUES
(1, 'aa'),
(2, 'ab'),
(3, 'ac'),
(4, 'ba'),
(5, 'bb'),
(6, 'bc'),
(7, 'ca'),
(8, 'cb'),
(9, 'cc')

select *
from (
    select *, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1) ORDER BY Name ASC) AS [Rank] 
    from @Customer
) tableWithRank
WHERE tableWithRank.Rank <= 2
```

Output:

```
1|  aa|1

2|  ab|2

4|  ba|1

5|  bb|2

7|  ca|1

8|  cb|2
```